# How to keep a window open on Window.Closing Event C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to know if there is a way to  keep a window open even after  pressing X. It will be a warning of sorts. When i press X on the main window the message box will apear with the error and when i press ok i want to return to the main window.

```
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs a)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Hello", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
  }
  private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
  {
     e.Cancel = true;
  }
```

There is a way to do that ? I am sorry for the bad explanation

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Why don't you prompt the user in the Clos**ing** event? The XXX**ed** - events are "after the fact", the XXX**ing** - events are "prior to". So what you want is to possibly abort closing, so you need to do everything in the "prior to" event.

Comment: How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 which you wanted:**

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBoxResult closingMessegeBoxResult = MessageBox.Show("Is it OK to close?", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
     if (closingMessegeBoxResult != MessageBoxResult.OK)
     {
         e.Cancel = true;
     }
}
```

Here is the Graphical result of it :

[Screen shot of result...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPWVS.png)

**Solution 2 which is for Pro WPF developers:**

is making your  WindowStyle=" None" on Xaml and making your own closing minimizing and maximizing buttons with a StackPanel few buttons and a mouse down button event for stack panel (for moving the window) which is linked to this handler :

```
  private void WindowStartedMoving(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
     DragMove();
  }
```

please ask me if you had any more questions :)

Comment: Can you please show me how did you bind the Window_Closing event in XAML?

Comment: Here it is buddy: ```<Window  Closing="Window_Closing" >``` Please tell me if you need something else :)